# Check for paypal subscription status in C#

Tags: c#, paypal, payment, subscription, recurring

I want to check for a user's subscription status in Paypal. I mean, if a user paid his last subscription fee I want paypal to redirect to a chosen page so I could extend his subscription date.

If it's not possible I would only like to know when a user's subscription is cancelled. Or maybe just send a request to paypal and check for that user's subscription status, whether it's paid for this month or not.

How would I achieve such a thing?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) PayPal will call a page on your site with a status, works for payments received, refunds etc. I am not sure if you can request last IPN status, but worth looking onto.
HTH